# How to achieve equivalent to Dissolve from ArcGIS for Desktop using ST_Union?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, dissolve

I am trying to achieve an equivalent to the Dissolve tool from ArcGIS for Desktop using ST_Union from PostGIS but it seems I am not getting expected result.

I have one table which has certain attributes with the Polygon Geometry. (like FID, Locstat, Loccnt, Shape)

Here is my query :

```
SELECT c.fid, ST_Union(c.boundaryshape) FROM c Group by c.fid,c.boundaryshape;
```

Comment: Can you explain what results you're expecting and what you're getting? Running: SELECT AsText(ST_Union...) FROM ... might help to find the error.

Comment: In table I have 6842 records, as per the ArcGIS results I should get 1683 records where as using the query I am getting 6842 records. I also tried ST_Aggr_Union which is give me 742 Records with the multiple null Geometry.

Answer (score 17):

Your problem is likely because of what you have included in the group by field.

ST_UNION is an aggregate function, meaning that it is dissolving based on what you specify as the `GROUP` parameter.

Here is what you entered:

`SELECT c.fid, ST_Union(c.boundaryshape) FROM c Group by c.fid,c.boundaryshape;`

According to this, you are grouping by your `fid`, which is probably a unique identifier, and also by `boundaryshape`, which is the geometry.  The problem with this is that it is highly unlikely that the features sharing a unique ID, are going to have identical geometries.  Therefore, the `ST_Union` is probably going to end up with something like the following:

```
Input:   
fid     boundaryshape  
1         11  
1         12  
1         11  
1         13  
2         12  
2         13  
2         12  
3          5  
3          2  
3          4  

Output:  
fid     boundaryshape  
1        (11 + 11)  
1        12  
1        13  
2        (12 + 12)  
2        13  
3        2  
3        4  
3        5
```

In this case, you should only be dissolving based on your unique identifier, unless you actually have a number of duplicate geometries with the same `fid`, that you are trying to get rid of.  Even in that situation though, you should only need to group based on the `fid`, and the union will take care of the geometry duplication.

I would try the following:

`SELECT c.fid, ST_Union(c.boundaryshape) FROM c GROUP BY c.fid;`

That should give you the desired result of dissolving all features based on the common attribute `fid`.

Here is the help document at the PostGIS site:  [ST_Union](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Union.html)

See the first example listed at the bottom and notice that it does not include the geometry in the group by section.

Comment: In some cases, it is better to snap geometries to grid before doing union: SELECT ST_Union(ST_SnapToGrid(geom,0.0001)) FROM geo_area  group by level_identifier;