# How can I get a single part dissolve using ST_Union or ST_Aggr_Union?

Tags: postgis, arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing, dissolve

I am trying to get dissolve functionality using `ST_Union` using this query :

```
SELECT c.fid, ST_Union(c.boundaryshape) FROM c GROUP BY c.fid;
```

Than I found instead of using `ST_Union` I should use `ST_Aggr_Union` :

```
SELECT c.fid, ST_Aggr_Union(c.boundaryshape) FROM c GROUP BY c.fid;
```

I am getting results like dissolve but it looks like this is multi-part.

Can somebody let me know how can I get the single-part dissolve?

Comment: I am curious how this is different from your previous question - [How to achieve equivalent to dissolve from ArcGIS for Desktop using ST_UNION](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71870/how-to-achieve-equivalent-to-dissolve-from-arcgis-for-desktop-using-st-union/71876#71876).  They seem like the same question.  ST_AGG_Union is not the proper function, as by definition it aggregates the results of all the unions into one geometry, creating a multi-part geometry.  If ST_Union is not working, then we need more detail as to what you did, your results, and your problem with the results.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is this:

```
SELECT c.fid, ST_UnaryUnion(ST_Collect(c.boundaryshape)) FROM c GROUP BY c.fid
```

[`ST_Collect`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_Collect.html) collects all the geometries into a `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION`.  Then [`ST_UnaryUnion`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_UnaryUnion.html) does the dissolving.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at ST_Dump(), e.g.:

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(ST_Union(c.boundaryshape)).geom FROM c;
```